# How to push Laravel 5.4 project to a server with PHP CLI version 5.4.16?

Tags: php, laravel

My client uses a server with Apache PHP version 5.6.30 but the CLI PHP version is 5.4.16. And they can't change the CLI PHP version.

I use Git && SSH to push the project to the server from my local machine. But since the CLI PHP version is 5.4.16, I can't run

```
composer install
```

I will get these messages

```
Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.4.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/var-dumper v3.3.2 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/var-dumper v3.3.2 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v3.3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.3.2].
```

The phpinfo() tells that the version of PHP is 5.6.30. So I guess that part should be fine. But I don't know that to solve this situation.

When I go to the website, I get these error messages:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 12

Warning: require(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 12

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/5.6/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 12
```

Comment: `/path/to/php-5.6 /path/to/composer install`

Comment: If the suggestion from @Devon doesn't work you can always try to cheat and directly copy up to the server a functioning PHP cli binary.  That, of course, can be a feat in and of itself.

Comment: @ceejayoz PHP 5.4 on CentOS/RHEL7 will receive security updates for another 5+ years, however, Plesk allows you to install other versions alongside the system version which is what the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using plesk, you should find the binary of other PHP versions at /opt/plesk/php.

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php /usr/bin/composer install
```

Comment: Actually this works. Dependencies getting install until I ran into this error message: php artisan optimize
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/artisan on line 31 Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255.   It seems like Laravel internally runs "php artisan" which does not point to the correct php version.

Comment: @JoshuaLeung yes, that is from composer.json, you can either modify that or just run the `/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php artisan` commands manually after.

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, you can also push the entire vendor folder along to the server.  All `composer install` really does is create the vendor folder.  If you upload your *entire* project folder, vendors included, then you will be able to run it on the server without running composer.  As long as the web version meets your minimum requirements, then this means that you should be able to effectively ignore the client version.

That being said, you'll run into this problem again if you need to run any tasks from the command line.